# Customizing Visual Studio 2012's Web Publishing Pipeline (WPP) for build server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild, msdeploy, msbuild-wpp

I'm working on creating a build and deployment infrastructure for a large corporate service infrastructure. We're using TFS Build 2012 for our Build Server, Visual Studio 2012 to generate WPP deployment packages, and MSDeploy 2.1 to perform the actual deployments. (We can't use MSDeploy 3 due to a number of bugs with it - NTLM authentication is broken with WMSvc, etc).

I've created a "Project.wpp.targets" file and added the following properties:

```
<DeployOnBuild Condition="$(DeployOnBuild) == '' And '$(OutDir)' != '$(OutputPath)' ">true</DeployOnBuild>
<WebPublishMethod>Package</WebPublishMethod>
<DeployManagedPipelineMode>Integrated</DeployManagedPipelineMode>
<Disable_CopyWebApplication>True</Disable_CopyWebApplication>
```

When the compile happens on the build server, OutDir will be different than OutputPath and WPP will be activated. The build outputs the following files:

```
Project.zip
Project.SetParameters.xml
Project.SourceManifest.xml
Project.deploy.cmd
Project.deploy-readme.txt
```

Inside project.zip are:

```
Archive.xml
Parameters.xml
systemInfo.xml
```

**Question 1** - What is the SourceManifest.xml file for, and why isn't it in the zip package?
It seems as though the entire reason for creating a zip file package for deployment is so that it's fully self contained. That SourceManifest file is "loose" - we can't just toss a zip file up on our deployment file share any longer. Why isn't it in the package? It also points at specific paths on the *build server*!

**Question 2** - What is the Archive.xml file for? It seems somewhat redundant to SourceManifest.xml - I see a  provider, a number of  providers, etc. In the Microsoft documentation they mention "manifest.xml" in the package. This file looks like the manifest, but it's called "archive.xml". Does the filename matter? Is manifest.xml different than archive.xml? How do they relate to SourceManifest.xml, which looks similar yet different at the same time?

**Question 3** - what is systemInfo.xml for? It appears to list all of the components installed for the IIS role on the build server. For example, if I run the build at command line on my local machine, it lists that .NET 2.0 and 4.0 are installed and a number of True/False values for the various IIS components on my machine. The problem is those settings have *no* bearing on what I actually want deployed! Does MSDeploy ever look at this file? Can it's generation be disabled? I definitely do not want configuration artifacts from the build server affecting production!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The zip package generated is self sufficient and can be used with msdeploy.exe without any of the other files in the directory.

You can prevent the *cmd* and *SetParameters* files from being generated by setting `GenerateSampleDeployScript=False`. You cannot configure *SourceManifest* to be deleted after a build, but you can safely do it manually.

**SourceManifest.xml** is basically a diagnostic artifact. In reality, it was the `-source:manifest=Project.SourceManifest.xml` to the sync's `-dest:package=Project.zip`

**archive.xml** is the package provider's internal representatio of what's in it. The file is always called archive.xml and the documentation mentioning manifest.xml is mistaken.

I'm not actually sure how **systeminfo.xml** is used. I don't know of a way to disable the functionality, but I've also never run into a situation where it's properties have affected a deployment.

Comment: Thanks!

I was able to remove the source manifest file by adding a custom target into the .wpp.targets file:   <Target Name="DeleteSourceManifest" AfterTargets="Package">
    <Delete Files="$(PackageSourceManifest)" Condition="Exists('$(PackageSourceManifest)')" />
  </Target>

As far as I can tell, systeminfo.xml is never used. Still, it's a bit annoying that its being generated with incorrect information.

Comment: This is the sort of information that belongs in "Web Deploy - The missing manual", clear and succinct.